# Basic jQuery slider javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working with a plugin called the Basic jQuery slider. The slider works fine only I've had the ridiculous request by a client to change the directions, so the slides slide out to the right as opposed to the left.

There isnt a variable for direction that I can set so im wondering how hard it is to customise this plugin?

I've gone through it changing certain values only I cant see to get it to work...

The script that carries out the animation is below...

```
else if (settings.animation === 'slide') {

                    if (settings.showMarkers) {

                        markers.eq(slidePosition - 1).removeClass('active-marker');

                        if (next === slideCount - 1) {
                            markers.eq(0).addClass('active-marker');
                        } else if (next === 0) {
                            markers.eq(slideCount - 3).addClass('active-marker');
                        } else {
                            markers.eq(next - 1).addClass('active-marker');
                        }

                    }

                    $slider.animate({
                        'left': -next * settings.width
                    }, settings.animationDuration, function () {

                        if (next === 0) {
                            slidePosition = slideCount - 2;
                            $slider.css({
                                'left': -slidePosition * settings.width
                            });
                        } else if (next === slideCount - 1) {
                            slidePosition = 1;
                            $slider.css({
                                'left': -settings.width
                            });
                        } else {
                            slidePosition = next;
                        }

                        animating = false;

                    });

                }
```

in instances of "left: -settings.width" I've tried changing to a + as opposed to minus only this doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Spent a good bit of time playing around with this - the plugin works by having the image elements and cloning the first and last. (the last element is cloned to the first spot, the first element cloned to the last) When a slide is changed it takes the index of the slide and multiplies it by the width to get the left positioning it needs to assume.  If it truly needs to be reversed (slides to the right rather than the left) I would honestly recommend going with a plugin that already does this or writing your own, the structure of this code didn't have reversibility in mind.

Comment: Thanks @Snuffleupagus, I've just started writing my own now...